# Incompatible delegate exception from Observable.FromEventPattern

Tags: system.reactive

I wrote the following handy (or so I thought) extension method for use with Rx and WPF:

```
public static IObservable<EventPattern<TViewModel, PropertyChangedEventArgs>>
            CreatePropertyChangedObservable<TViewModel>(this TViewModel vm) where TViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            return Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventHandler, TViewModel, PropertyChangedEventArgs>(
                h => vm.PropertyChanged += h, h => vm.PropertyChanged -= h);
        }
```

In some projects, this works fine. But in others, I get an `ArgumentException` with the message "Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type" from deep within the Rx code when I try to subscribe a delegate to the returned observable. My delegate absolutely has the right signature, and the exact same code with the exact same types succeeds in one project yet fails in the other. Both projects reference the same version of the System.Reactive nuget package (4.3.1).

If I use the more weakly-typed version of FromEventPattern (without TViewModel) and then manually `Select` the `EventPattern<PropertyChangedEventArgs>` into an `EventPattern<TViewModel, PropertyChangedEventArgs>`, it works fine in both projects. But I shouldn't have to do that.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in Rx? The callstack for the exception is as follows:

```
mscorlib.dll!System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(System.Type type, object firstArgument, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, bool throwOnBindFailure)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(System.Type type, object firstArgument, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method)    Unknown
System.Reactive.dll!System.Reactive.ReflectionUtils.CreateDelegate<System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler>(object o, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method) Line 24    C#
System.Reactive.dll!System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.EventProducer<System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler, System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>.Session.Initialize() Line 323   C#
System.Reactive.dll!System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.EventProducer<System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler, System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>.Session.Connect(System.IObserver<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>> observer = {System.Reactive.AnonymousSafeObserver<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>}) Line 269 C#
System.Reactive.dll!System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.EventProducer<System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler, System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>.Run(System.IObserver<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>> observer) Line 228  C#
System.Reactive.dll!System.Reactive.BasicProducer<System.__Canon>.SubscribeRaw.AnonymousMethod__1_0((System.Reactive.BasicProducer<System.__Canon> this, System.Reactive.Disposables.SingleAssignmentDisposable runAssignable, System.IObserver<System.__Canon> observer) tuple) Line 60    C#
System.Reactive.dll!System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.ScheduleAction.AnonymousMethod__76_0(System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler _, (System.Func<(System.__Canon, System.__Canon, System.__Canon), System.IDisposable> action, (System.__Canon, System.__Canon, System.__Canon) state) tuple) Line 88  C#
System.Reactive.dll!System.Reactive.Concurrency.CurrentThreadScheduler.Schedule<System.ValueTuple<System.Func<(System.Reactive.BasicProducer<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>, System.Reactive.Disposables.SingleAssignmentDisposable, System.IObserver<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>), System.IDisposable>, (System.Reactive.BasicProducer<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>, System.Reactive.Disposables.SingleAssignmentDisposable, System.IObserver<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>)>>((System.Func<(System.Reactive.BasicProducer<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>, System.Reactive.Disposables.SingleAssignmentDisposable, System.IObserver<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>), System.IDisposable>, (System.Reactive.BasicProducer<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>, System.Reactive.Disposables.SingleAssignmentDisposable, System.IObserver<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>)) state, System.TimeSpan dueTime, System.Func<System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler, (System.Func<(System.Reactive.BasicProducer<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>, System.Reactive.Disposables.SingleAssignmentDisposable, System.IObserver<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>), System.IDisposable>, (System.Reactive.BasicProducer<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>, System.Reactive.Disposables.SingleAssignmentDisposable, System.IObserver<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>)), System.IDisposable> action) Line 101 C#
System.Reactive.dll!System.Reactive.Concurrency.LocalScheduler.Schedule<System.ValueTuple<System.Func<(System.Reactive.BasicProducer<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>, System.Reactive.Disposables.SingleAssignmentDisposable, System.IObserver<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>), System.IDisposable>, (System.Reactive.BasicProducer<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>, System.Reactive.Disposables.SingleAssignmentDisposable, System.IObserver<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>)>>((System.Func<(System.Reactive.BasicProducer<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>, System.Reactive.Disposables.SingleAssignmentDisposable, System.IObserver<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>), System.IDisposable>, (System.Reactive.BasicProducer<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>, System.Reactive.Disposables.SingleAssignmentDisposable, System.IObserver<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>)) state, System.Func<System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler, (System.Func<(System.Reactive.BasicProducer<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>, System.Reactive.Disposables.SingleAssignmentDisposable, System.IObserver<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>), System.IDisposable>, (System.Reactive.BasicProducer<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>, System.Reactive.Disposables.SingleAssignmentDisposable, System.IObserver<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>)), System.IDisposable> action) Line 32   C#
System.Reactive.dll!System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.ScheduleAction<System.ValueTuple<System.Reactive.BasicProducer<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>, System.Reactive.Disposables.SingleAssignmentDisposable, System.IObserver<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>>>(System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler scheduler, (System.Reactive.BasicProducer<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>, System.Reactive.Disposables.SingleAssignmentDisposable, System.IObserver<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>) state, System.Func<(System.Reactive.BasicProducer<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>, System.Reactive.Disposables.SingleAssignmentDisposable, System.IObserver<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>), System.IDisposable> action) Line 86    C#
System.Reactive.dll!System.Reactive.BasicProducer<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>>.SubscribeRaw(System.IObserver<System.Reactive.EventPattern<MyViewModel, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>> observer, bool enableSafeguard) Line 62   C#
```

Comment: What is the signature of the delegates that are causing you grief?

Comment: @Enigmativity There are generics involved, but I get the same result with everything I try. One example is `void(EventPattern<ApplicationSettingsViewModel, PropertyChangedEventArgs> ep)` where `ApplicationSettingsViewModel` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I get the exception regardless of whether I use a lambda, a static function, or a member function.

Comment: A complexity is that `ApplicationSettingsViewModel` is defined in one project, `FromEventPattern` is being called in another, and `Subscribe` is being called in a third.

Comment: Can you please change the code in your question to provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Enigmativity unfortunately no. The problem only occurs in one of my projects; seemingly identical code in other projects works fine. I've tried to reproduce the issue in vitro, but haven't yet managed to do it.

Comment: Then it's probably time to delete the question and move on. Unless you can actually replicate the issue in a minimal example then we've got no hope of guess why this working code fails in one specific environment.

Comment: @Enigmativity Well; maybe. Or maybe someone could say "what you're trying to do here is obviously wrong and I'm surprised it only failed in one place," or "yes, this is a known issue in Rx 4.3.1," or someone else could stumble onto the same problem and find this question, and by combining my info with theirs, the solution could emerge...

Comment: That hasn't happened yet. Persevering with trying to create a [mcve] will either answer it for you or give us a shot at helping.